# Inserting Row into Database with Array Values

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I'm having trouble getting the last array in the function below to insert into the table. I'm guessing a syntax issue, but I am not finding it and need help.  The function inserts database values upon plugin activation on a Wordpress installation:

```
function my_plugin_install_function() {
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "revslider_sliders";
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 
           'title' => 'test',
           'alias' => 'test2',
           'params' => array (
                'title' => 'Homepage Slider',
                'alias' => 'homepage-slider',
                'shortcode' => '[rev_slider homepage-slider]',
                'slider_type' => 'fixed',
                'width' => 875,
                'height' => 350,
                'responsitive_w1' => 'NULL',
                'responsitive_sw1' => 'NULL', 
                'responsitive_w2' => 'NULL', 
                'responsitive_sw2' => 'NULL',
                'responsitive_w3' => 'NULL',
                'responsitive_sw3' => 'NULL',
                'responsitive_w4' => 'NULL',
                'responsitive_sw4' => 'NULL',
                'responsitive_w5' => 'NULL',
                'responsitive_sw5' => 'NULL',
                'responsitive_w6' => 'NULL',
                'responsitive_sw6' => 'NULL',
                'delay' => 8000,
                'touchenabled' => 'on',
                'stop_on_hover' => 'on',
                'shuffle' => 'off',
                'load_googlefont' => 'true',
                'google_font' => 'PT+Sans',
                'stop_slider' => 'off', 
                'stop_after_loops' => 0, 
                'stop_at_slide' => 2, 
                'position' => 'center', 
                'margin_top' => 0, 
                'margin_bottom' => 0,
                'margin_left' => 0, 
                'margin_right' => 0, 
                'shadow_type' => 3, 
                'show_timerbar' => 'false', 
                'timebar_position' => 'top',
                'background_color' => '#fff', 
                'padding' => 5, 
                'show_background_image' => 'true', 
                'background_image' => 'NULL', 
                'navigation_type' => 'bullet', 
                'navigation_arrows' => 'verticalcentered', 
                'navigation_style' => 'navbar-old', 
                'nav_offset_hor' => 0, 
                'nav_offset_vert' => 20, 
                'navigaion_always_on' => 'false', 
                'hide_thumbs' => 200, 
                'thumb_width' => 100, 
                'thumb_height' => 50, 
                'thumb_amount' => 5, 
                'hide_slider_under' => 0, 
                'hide_defined_layers_under' => 0, 
                'hide_all_layers_under' => 0,
                'jquery_noconflict' => 'on',
                'js_to_body' => 'false', 
                'output_type' => 'none',
                )
         ), array('%s', '%s', '')
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess appears:

```
'params' => array (//...
    'output_type' => 'none',
)
```

Take that last comma ( `,` ) away after `'none'`

Line becomes

```
'output_type' => 'none'
```

I am not familiar with WP functions, but that is a common syntax error. That sure does show a PHP error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the syntax fix, but that does not solve the problem.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb says:

> Possible format values: %s as string; %d as decimal number; and %f as
>   float.

You are not able to add Array() to database. That makes no sense to me and to the function $wpdb->insert() because third parameter's `array('%s', '%s', '')` third value: ' '  needs to be one of following: %s, %d or %f

I have two suggestions

### Method 1

You could alter the database structure (example columns):

```
title, alias, params_title, params_alias, params_shortcode, ... , params_output_type
```

And save params individually like this:

```
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 
           'title' => 'test',
           'alias' => 'test2',
           'params_title' => 'Homepage Slider',
           'params_alias' => 'homepage-slider',
           'params_shortcode' => '[rev_slider homepage-slider]', //(...)
            ), array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') // Add as many %s or %d as needed
           );
```

### Method 2

Or save params array(); as string like this (see those ""-characters) `"array (/* ... */)"`

```
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 
           'title' => 'test',
           'alias' => 'test2',
           'params' => "array (
                'title' => 'Homepage Slider',
                'alias' => 'homepage-slider',
                'shortcode' => '[rev_slider homepage-slider]',
                /* ... */
           )"
         ), array('%s', '%s', '%s')
   );
```

And on PHP-code where you get those out of the database use something like this

```
eval("\$params = \"{$row['params']}\";");
```

That eval() sets $params-variable to:

```
$params = array (
                'title' => 'Homepage Slider',
                'alias' => 'homepage-slider',
                'shortcode' => '[rev_slider homepage-slider]',
                /* ... */
                );
```

Got it :)?

Comment: Hi Joni, I might be about this totally wrong - all I want to do is make the LAST column in the row have values that look like this, using `insert()`: `{"title":"Homepage Slider #2","alias":"homepage-slider-2","shortcode":"[rev_slider homepage-slider-2]","slider_type":"responsitive"......`  So maybe I should be adding in a different way into the DB.